# Form handling and validation in Google spreadsheet sidebar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a sidebar in a Google spreadsheet with a HTML form in it.
Now, how do I handle the values submitted?

In `index.html`:

```
 <form id="configs" action="#">
 <fieldset>
 ////input fields here
<input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Send" onclick="google.script.run.validarForm()" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

In `code.gs` the functin validarForm() is called but how do I pass the submitted values to it so I can validate it first and store them in variables?

Thanks in advance for your help!﻿

Answer (score 2):

You can pass [parameters using google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)). I'd do something like this:

```
<form id="configs" action="#">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" id="exampleField1" />
<input type="text" id="exampleField2" />
<input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Send" onclick="enviarForm()" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<script>
function enviarForm(){
  var exampleField1Value = document.getElementById("exampleField1").value;
  var exampleField2Value = document.getElementById("exampleField2").value;

  google.script.run.validarForm(exampleField1Value, exampleField2Value);
}
</script>
```

Of course, this can be done with event handlers instead of "onclick=", and jQuery too.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I don't think document.getElementById works in GAS

Comment: Give it a try. I've done something similar using the HTML Service a number of times. There are a few peculiarities, but it's basically just standard Javascript.